# Excel formula to get string between 2 characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to dynamically extract the string between 2 characters in Excel using a formula (no text to columns). The sample data is:

```
US - Blue Widgets - Net
UK - Green - Grass
UAE - Red - Apples
```

* Note that the data doesn't have fixed length

I tried using a formula, but I think I'm missing something because that also returns the string after the last `-`.

Formula:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","|",1))+1,LEN(A2)),"_",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2)))
```

what this returns is:

```
Blue Widgets - Net
Green - Grass
Red - Apples
```

here's what I'd like it to return:

```
Blue Widgets
Green
Red
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
=TRIM(MID(A2, 6, FIND("-",A2,6) - FIND("-",A2) - 2))
```

If hard coded 6 is not ok, you can replace it with FIND("-", A2) + 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from the following link, its pretty useful,,

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/444266-extract-string-between-two-characters.html

Answer (score 0):

I used this and worked.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","|",1))+1,LEN(A3)),"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A3))),LEN(A3)))," ","")),"",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","|",1))+1,LEN(A3)),"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A3))),LEN(A3)))," ",""))
```

you will get:

Blue Widgets
Green
Red

is you want to get the last part, I mean the string after the second "-"
use this

```
=IF(ISERROR(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","|",2))+1,LEN(A3)),"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A3))),LEN(A3)))," ","")),"",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","|",2))+1,LEN(A3)),"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A3))),LEN(A3)))," ",""))
```

you will get:

Net
Grass
Apples

Best regads.