# Extract data from cell in excel

Tags: excel

I need to extract data from excel cell. The data is locked between two brackets.
For example: if I have `DYT[[AU7]]YHU` in a cell, I need to extract `AU7`.

Edit:

I'm having this formula: `MID(A2,FIND("[",A2)+1,FIND("]",A2)-FIND("[",A2)-1)`
but I'm getting `[AU7` instead `AU7`

Can someone told me where's my mistake?
Thank you in advance

Comment: you want data in gridview?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871603/excel-formula-to-get-string-between-2-characters

Comment: Use: `=MID(A2,FIND("[",A2)+2,FIND("]",A2)-FIND("[",A2)-2)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I found an answer:

`MID(A2,FIND("[",A2)+2,FIND("]",A2)-FIND("[",A2)-2)`

Thanks for those who tried to help!